# Grid UI PageActions How to show plain text?

Tags: magento2, grid

I am developing the action link in the grid ui component.
I try to add a condition that if customer is not allow to view, remove the hyperlink and show "Not Allowed" in plain text.

I know how to add a hyperlink in the pageactions class but I cannot find a way to show the plain text. Follows is the code I tried.

```
if ($isAllow) {
    $href = $this->getContext()->getUrl("custom/lesson/lessoninfo",["lesson_id"=>$item['lesson_id'], "product_id"=>$item['product_id']]);
            $label = "View";
    } else {
            $href = "";
            $label = "Not Allow";
    }

            $item[$name]["view"] = [
                "href"=>$href,
                "label"=>$label
            ];
```

The hyperlink is not removed and if I click into the link. It will go to current page and add undefined after the url.

Comment: try `$href = "#"`  instead of blank

Answer (score 0):

This can only happen when it is not going to your condition

Refer this function

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                    'edit' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(static::URL_PATH_EDIT, ['id' => $item['entity_id']]),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ],
                    'delete' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(static::URL_PATH_DELETE, ['id' => $item['entity_id']]),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.mydata }"'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete this?')
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

Here `if(isset($item['entity_id']))` this is not satisfied it will not go inside and print your result as a result you may see a blank column. Try referring same in your code.

**Updated As Per Your Requirement**

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (isset($item['entity_id']) && $item['entity_id'] != null) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                    'edit' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(static::URL_PATH_EDIT, ['id' => $item['entity_id']]),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ]
                ];
            } else {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                    'edit' => [
                        'label' => __('N/A')
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

Comment: you are correct but what should I do if I need to show plain text "Not Allowed"  in the column ?

Comment: It is too ugly in the component if some row show blank column refer to your code. Just need a word to show if it is not allowed.